# Check if email exists in sql database and output thereafter (regarding running if inside if)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, if-statement

So I have a form running on a page that I'm experimenting with. Atm I just have one input and that is email. Basically I want a register and if a person tries to add the same email again it will return an error msg and otherwise it will add it.

So this is the code I've been posting with:

```
<?php
    $username="user";
    $password="pass";
    $database="test";
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE email='$email' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
        print 'user is already in table';
    }
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO enroll VALUES ('','$email')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());       
        print 'user added';
    }
?>
```

That works fine! If I add an email that already exists it says "user is already in table" and if not it says "user added".

Problem is that before I used to run another php script which validated the input and then upon submit it added it to the DB. Now it ALWAYS says "user is already in table" even before I've pressed Submit.

I would like to do something like this, but when posting it doesn't work at all and I can't understand what's wrong.

```
<?php
    //If the form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // Required field names
        $required = array('email');

        // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
        $error = false;
        foreach($required as $field) {
            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $error = true;
            }
        }

            if ($error) {
                echo 'You forgot to fill in your email';
            } else {
                $username="user";
                $password="pass";
                $database="test";
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );

                mysqli_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
                mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE email='$email' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) ) {
                    print 'user is already in table';
                }
                else {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO enroll VALUES ('','$email')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
                    print 'user added';
                }
            }
    }
```

?>

In my world, this checks if email is supplied, checks if it exists in db and if not adds it. If it exists it will come back with an error.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2: @ExpertSystem This is the code I'm going with now as per your recommendation:

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            // Required field names
            $required = array('email');

            // Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
            $error = false;
            foreach($required as $field) {
                if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                $error = true;
                }
            }

                if ($error) {
                    echo 'You forgot to fill in your email';
                } else {
                    $username="root";
                    $password="root";
                    $host="localhost";
                    $database="test";
                    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );

                    $link = mysqli_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
                    mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die("Unable to select database");

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE email='$email'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) ) {
                        print 'user is already in table';
                    }
                    else {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO enroll (email) VALUES ('$email')";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                        print 'user added';
                    }
                }
        }
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: `@mysql_select_db` ***never*** do this. Suppressing errors is just poor, poor practice.

Comment: Using the mysql root user in ANY public-facing code is a VERY BAD idea.

Comment: +1 because you showed proper effort before asking here!

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to mysqli_ and also removed @. Will still keep the root user since this atm is internal and local (will change this later).

Comment: Please update the question with your changed code (MySQLi, removed `@` etc.).

Comment: Have you checked and made sure that the e-mail isn't already added in the DB (e.g. from previous tests) ? I can't spot any reason, why this shouldn't work. Perhaps printing the `$result` returned from the SQL-query would shed some light.

Comment: Okay, I just updated the question with full .php content

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yes, the db is empty. Won't add anything. But if I run the strings by themselves it work fine. It's just when I put them together that nothing happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the procedural form of the `mysqli_` functions, you need to pass a *mysqli link identifier* as the first argument in `mysqli_select_db()`, `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_error()` (see also the **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** for more details). The aforementioned *mysqli link identifier* is the object returned by `mysqli_connect()`.
The modified code should look something like this:

```
...
$link = mysqli_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die("Unable to select database");
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]);
...
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
...
if...
    ...
} else {
    ...
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    ...
...
```

Comment: @user1662786: Have you tried that ? Did it solve the problem ?

Comment: I've tried this now but still nothing, when I submit it loads but nothing get added to the db :/

Comment: When you submit, what is returned/echoed ? "user is already in table" ?

Comment: okay, sorry to bother you, but I fooled you a little bit. It's working now to submit ONE time and it adds an entry in my DB with id=1 but email value is empty and i can't add any more email addresses at all.

I removed what you asked me to change and added it as it were before and then it also works but I get "Unable to select database"

Comment: yes, now it's echoing "user is already in database" alltho nothing is in the db, just an empty row with id=1 and nothing under email

Comment: I don't have time to double check at the moment, but if you want, try the following: **1.** Change it back to how it is in my answer. **2.** Replace `$query = "INSERT INTO enroll VALUES ('','$email')";` with `$query = "INSERT INTO enroll (email) VALUES ('$email')";`. **3.** Run it and let me know if it worked so I can update my answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm grateful for your help :) I tried it now and it's still the same issue. I submit an email, it says "added", in db I get a new row with ID but no email, and if i try any email again it just says "email already exists".

Comment: Are you sure you changed the second `$query` exactly as in my comment above ? Please add `print $query` under the second `$query` and report what is prints. (Sorry to have you try so many things, but I am shooting in the dark here :))

Comment: I updated the code I'm using in my original question now and tried the print query. First time (after clearing my enroll table) it prints "INSERT INTO enroll (email) VALUES ('')", and second time after that it prints "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE email=''" (Note, i added print $query instead of "user already exists")

Comment: So, your `$email` variable is the problem. How about adding `print $_POST['email'] . "<br>" . $email;` right **after** `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string...` ?

Comment: then I get the following: "test@test.com
user is already in table". But I tried something different. I removed the "i" in "mysqli_real_escape_string" and went with the old "mysql_real_escape_string", now everything works as it should. It adds addresses and prompts me if it already exists. So that seems to be the problem, strange tho

Comment: Ooops ! That's my fault I guess :( Please, don't use `mysql_`. Instead, use `mysqli_` correctly :) So, I corrected my answer: You have to add `$link` as parameter in `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (and therefore you have to move it **after** `$link = mysqli_connect...`). Now everything should work fine. Please, don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted", if it helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: Just so that you know: The reason that `mysql_real_escape_string(...)` works without an _link_ parameter, while its `mysqli_` counterpart doesn't, is that in `mysql_` functions the _link_ parameter is optional and defaults to the last opened connection. In `mysqli_` functions the _link_ parameter is **required** (when using them in procedural style).

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help! Now it's working exactly as it should! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

My head says, "mysqli_num_rows($result);" returns an integer.
So you can't do if(mysqli_num_rows($result)), it will always return an integer (e.g. 0 or 1)

So try this:

```
 if (1==mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                print 'already in table';
 }
```

Just a thought.

Comment: I tried it now, problem is that nothing happend. Page reloads as if it where to add it to the DB but "email" in db is empty, while everything works by itself.

Comment: So, tried to understand your answer.. The script should be print 'already in table' if there is already exact the email you want to insert.

Comment: @PhillipColumbia: In PHP, in `if(0)...`, the condition is evaluated as `FALSE`, so there is nothing wrong about `if (musqli_num_rows($result))...` :(

Comment: @Expert System: Okay but than, I have no more idea. I should try this code on my own.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help! Hopefully I've at least improved my bad code with your help.

I found out what's causing the problem and it was this.

```
<input type="submit">
```

I changed that to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

And of course now everything works. Thanks tho! :)